# Plot simplices in 3D in R

Tags: r, plot3d

I have a list of points and a list of simplices. I would like to plot  the simplices in 3D given their vertices. Essentially, I am looking for the equivalent of segment() in 3D.

Example

```
Pts<-matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),ncol =3,byrow=TRUE)
Simplex<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

So, I am looking for a way to input Pts and Simplex and getting a plot of the tetrahedron.

I’ve tried searching but so far the only possibility seems to write out the functions for the linear spaces and plot those. Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `nock=3`? Did you mean `ncol=3`? And can you provide an example image representative of what you want (if possible)? I'm not too familiar with the terminology of simplices.

Comment: @thelatemail A simplex in 3D is nothing but a tetrahedron.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - cool, thanks, not a term I'd heard before. Nice answer by the way.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, that was an IPhone-introduced typo. Thanks for pointing it out. Names of small-dimensional simplices are:  a 0-simplex is a point,
a 1-simplex is a line segment,
a 2-simplex is a triangle,
a 3-simplex is a tetrahedron,
a 4-simplex is a 5-cell. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the *'rgl'* package:

```
library(rgl)

vertices <- rbind(
  c(0, 0, 0),
  c(1, 0, 0),
  c(0, 1, 0),
  c(0, 0, 1)
)

faces <- combn(4,3)
for(f in 1:4){
  triangles3d(rbind(
    vertices[faces[1,f],],
    vertices[faces[2,f],],
    vertices[faces[3,f],]
  ), color="red", alpha=0.4)
}
```

[image]

You can add the edges and the vertices:

```
# add edges as thin cylinders
edges <- combn(4, 2)
for(e in 1:6){
  shade3d(cylinder3d(rbind(vertices[edges[1,e],],vertices[edges[2,e],]), 
                     radius = 0.02, sides = 30), col="yellow")
}
# add vertices as small spheres
spheres3d(vertices, radius= 0.03, color = "yellow")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not as pretty or flexible, but here's a base R version using `persp` and `segments` for fun:

```
## empty perspective plot
tm <- persp(matrix(rep(0,4), nrow=2),
            xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), zlim=c(-1,1),
            col="#00000000", border=NA, theta=30, phi=50, xlab="x")

## project points into 3d space
tpts <- data.frame(trans3d(pmat=tm, x=Pts[,1], y=Pts[,2], z=Pts[,3]))

## draw each segment
sgs <- combn(seq_len(nrow(tpts)), 2,
             FUN=function(r) unlist(tpts[r,]), simplify=FALSE)
lapply(sgs, function(x) segments(x[1], x[3], x[2], x[4], col="red"))
```

[image]

Comment: The previous answer is more relevant for me, but this is very useful too. Thank you!